# Keyboard and touchpad stopped working on Windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, touchpad

My keyboard and track pad suddenly stopped working at the same time on my HP Envy laptop. I think it was after updating a whole lot of drivers, but I cannot be sure as I generally use USB keyboard/mouse.

In Device Manager, the keyboard is not showing up at all (even if I select to display hidden devices). The track pad displays, but it shows the following error:

> insufficient system resources exist to complete the api

I know that it is not a hardware problem, because if I start up in BIOS, both the keyboard and trackpad work correctly.

I also noticed that in Device Manager under Human Interface Devices there is something called ELAN EzTouchFilter which is displaying the following message:

```
This device cannot be started. (Code 10)

A required I2C connection and/or interrupt resource was missing.
```

Attempting to update the drivers on either the trackpad or the Elan EzTouchFilter both just result in it telling me I already have the most up to date drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I decided to try "uninstall device" on the ELAN EzTouchFilter. After doing this, I restarted my machine and then both the keyboard and track pad started functioning correctly again.

Please note: I don't really know what the ELAN EzTouchFilter is, or why it was causing this problem. However, uninstalling it appears to have solved the problems for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled ELAN EzTouchFilter driver in device manager, then restart the computer. Keyboard and track pad work fine now.